# preventing automatic detection of email addresses

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, pdf, links

I'm trying to use [this](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/medium-length-professional-cv) resume template.

When I compile the document, pdflatex is automatically detecting the email addresses in the header and formatting it as a clickable (mailto) link. I would like to **disable** this functionality, such that the email addresses appears as non-clickable plaintext.

I've tried using things like `\usepackage[draft=true]{hyperref}`, but to no avail. Any suggestions on how to disable this automatic detection of email addresses? Thanks! :)

EDIT 1: The line in question, from the template, is:

```
\address{(000)~$\cdot$~111~$\cdot$~1111 \\ john@smith.com}
```

As you can see, no command surrounds the "john@smith.com".

EDIT 2: RESOLVED. It was Mac Preview auto-detecting the link. Oops :P

Comment: You can use `hidelinks` option to `hyperref`. Is that working?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: Then you have to show your code. Without it, we won't be able to operate.

Comment: If I compile the "template" as-is, there is no hyperlink. So it has to be something you are adding. We need to see the exact code you are using.

Comment: @NicholasHanson-Holtry: I agree with Paul Gessler: There is no automatic detection as far as I know, at least on Linux

Comment: I added the line from the template. When I compile the template, it _does_ turn into a link for me...?

Comment: @NicholasHanson-Holtry which PDF viewer are you using? It maybe is trying to be "smart" and is adding a link for you. I compiled the template and opened the PDF with SumatraPDF, Adobe Reader, and Adobe Acrobat Pro: in all cases, there is no hyperlink.

Comment: AH. This is Mac Preview imposing the link, not pdflatex. Thank you both so much :)

Comment: @NicholasHanson-Holtry: The link itself is there. Adobe Reader can be configured to detect links (urls) and automatically open the relevant program

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the hyperlink was introduced by the PDF viewer, not TeX-related software/package.